# Remove or disable button from layout related with an intent

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

I have an intent:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
```

There is a layout (with a button) related with MyActivity.

How can I remove or disable the button in myIntent?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly do it like that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
Bundle msges = new Bundle();
msges.putString("disableTheBtn", "yes");
intent.putExtras(msges);
startActivity(intent);
```

And inside **MyActivity class**

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ---------Do some thing , Button and GUI initialization-------
        try{ 
            String  disableTheBtn = getIntent().getExtras().getString("disableTheBtn"));
           if (disableTheBtn != null && !disableTheBtn.isEmpty(){
              yourBtn.setVisibilty(View.GONE);//hide that button
           } 
       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStack();
       } 
   }
```